# Is it possible to create function keys shortcuts in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to create a shortcut that uses the F1 key in SwiftUI.
The following code doesn't work.

```swift
Button("A Button") {
    /* some action here */
}.keyboardShortcut(KeyEquivalent("f1"))
```

Comment: You are not supposed to use function keys, they are reserved for system use.